# Deploy user event script to get all fields and values from all suitelets deployed in Netsuite ERP

Tags: javascript, netsuite, erp

Is there a way to deploy a user event script to get all fields and values from all suitelets deployed in Netsuite ERP as same as we usually do with record types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can't access fields in user event script from suitelet but you can use javascript event handlers in suitelet.

Comment: yes, thanks! 
but where  do I write code and attached in Netsuite that would trigger on change on suitelets?

Comment: you can write within suitelet or you can add as a lib